# Numpy: swap values of 2D array based on a separate vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Let's say I have a 3x4 numpy array, like so:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 0]]
```

And let's say that I have an additional vector:

```
[2,
 1,
 2,
 1]
```

For each row, I want to find the index of the value found in my additional vector, and swap it with the first column in my numpy array.

For example, the first entry in my vector is `2`, and in the first row of my numpy array, `2` is in the 3rd column, so I want to swap the first and third columns for that row, and continue this for each additional row.

```
[[2, 1, 0], # the number in the 0th position (0) and 2 have swapped placement
 [1, 0, 2], # the number in the 0th position (2) and 1 have swapped placement
 [2, 0, 1], # the number in the 0th position (0) and 2 have swapped placement
 [1, 2, 0]  # the number in the 0th position (1) and 1 have swapped placement
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show your current code from your research

Comment: Also, how does an index of `1` transform `[2, 0, 1],` into `[1, 0, 2]` if you're swapping with the 0th index of the row? Several of the swaps don't seem to match with your description at all.

Comment: It's a different question. In the second row, I'm not swapping the 0th index with 1st index, for example. I'm getting the index of where the value of 1, which is the second index, and then performing the swap. Sorry it was unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I've reopened the question

Comment: @Markus I closed and reopened that dupe, it's a different question

Comment: The description of the output still doesn't make sense to me and the unclear vote was lost on reopening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2],  [2, 0, 1],  [0, 2, 1],  [1, 2, 0]])
vals = np.array([2,  1,  2,  1])
```

First, you need to find the index of your values, which we can accomplish using broadcasting and `argmax` (This will find the *first* index, not necessarily the *only* index):

```
idx = (arr == vals[:, None]).argmax(1)
# array([2, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Now using basic indexing and assignment:

```
r = np.arange(len(arr))
arr[r, idx], arr[:, 0] = arr[:, 0], arr[r, idx]
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```